# Disabling 'Edit Properties' in document libarary across documents

Tags: properties, edit

In sharepoint 2007 document library, when documents are uploaded, across each documents there is an option that allows us to 'Edit properties' for that document. How do we disable this option. We wish to disable this option so that our users do not mess up the properties fields in there.

Thank you,
Mahesh

Comment: Ask at Server Fault - this is not a programming issue.

Comment: Unless it is.  Sharepoint is a programming platform as well.

Comment: This is only not a programming issue if there's a Sharepoint setting to change this, which I'm not sure there is.  A custom page for that screen would solve it, but that's programming-related...

Answer (score 0):

As noted on [SharePoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134826/i-want-to-disable-edit-properties-from-a-sharepoint-form-library/169523#169523): In SharePoint 2007 you'd have to modify `core.js`. (Or copy `core.js`, modify the copy and create a custom masterpage that includes the copied `core.js` instead of the original - since modifications on `core.js` are not supported.)